# Formal construction of the Cantor set $K$ and determination of $[0,1]\setminus K.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Let $J_{0,1}:=[0,1]$.

> **Step 1.** We remove the central open interval $I_{0,1}=\big(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\big)$. We denote with $J_{1,1}:=\big[0,\frac{1}{3}\big]$ and with $J_{1,2}:=\big[\frac{2}{3},1\big]$.
>
> We define $K_1:=J_{1,1}\cup J_{1,2}$ then $\complement{K_1}=I_{0,1}.$
>
> **Step 2.** We remove from $J_{1,1}$ and $J_{1,2}$ the central open interval of length $\frac{1}{9}$. Then we define what remains with $K_2:=J_{2,1}\cup J_{2,2}\cup J_{2,3}\cup J_{2,4}$, where $J_{2,1}=\big[0,\frac{1}{9}\big]$, $J_{2,2}=\big[\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}\big]$, $J_{2,3}=\big[\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9}\big]$, $J_{2,4}=\big[\frac{8}{9}, 1\big]$.
> At this point we define with $I_{1,1}=\big(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}\big)$, $I_{1,2}=\big(\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9}\big)$ the two open interval just removed. Therefore, $\complement{K_2}=\complement{K_1}\cup \big(I_{1,1}\cup I_{1,2}\big)$
>
> At the end of step $n$ we will have $2^n$ close interval $J_{n,k}$ for $k=1,\cdots, 2^n$ of length $1/3^n.$

---

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define $$K_{n}:=\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n} J_{n,k}$$
We define the Cantor set $K$ in the follow way $$K:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty} K_n.$$
In general, as discussed above, $$\complement{K_n}= \complement{K_{n-1}}\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n/2} I_{n-1,k}\tag1$$

> **Question 1.** It's correct (1)?

We determine,
$$[0,1]\setminus K=[0,1]\cap \bigg[\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\complement{K_{n-1}}\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n/2} I_{n-1,k}\bigg]\tag2$$

> **Question 2.** How can I proceed in (2)? I would like to prove that $$[0,1]\setminus K =\bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n}I_{n,k}.$$

### My answer at question 2.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
[0,1]\setminus K &= [0,1]\cap\bigg[\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\complement{K_n}\bigg]\\
=&\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \complement{K_n}\\
=&\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\complement{K_{n-1}}\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n/2}I_{n-1,k}\\
\color{BLUE}{=}& \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n/2} I_{n-1,k}\\
\color{RED}{=}&\bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n} I_{n,k}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
For the blue equality I used the fact that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\complement{K_{n-1}}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n/2}I_{n-1,k} $$
and the red equality it is a simple rewriting of the indexes.

> **Question 3.** It's correct my answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I think (1) is correct. For proving it, it is helpful to use ternary expansions, since the n-th iteration of the cantor set is the subset of [0,1] that in its ternary expansion all the first n elements aren't one. The complement, is the subset that  the first n elements of the ternary expansion there is at least one 1, and by the way you define it, I think you can prove the equivalence . And maybe this is helpful to prove (2) as well.